# PHP array in str_replace causing white screen error

Tags: php

so this line works on my local machine, but causes a white screen error on the server...

```
echo str_replace( ['<ul>','</ul>'], '', $string );
```

... and this line works great on both:

```
echo str_replace( array('<ul>','</ul>'), '', $string );
```

Any ideas on why?

Comment: What PHP version is the server running?  Shorthand arrays I believe are only supported on 5.4+

Comment: php version difference is causing the issue.

Comment: White screen means you are not showing errors. `ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL); error_reporting(1);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because your server version of PHP must be less that 5.4

It is a [new feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP 5.4 , It is called *Short array syntax*